# How to expect a logger to throw an error and pass a unit test at the same time?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, logging, async-await, jestjs

I've got a function which I need to write a unit test for. I'm going to "forget" to pass one parameter, so I expect a logger to log an error.
I use `jest` framework.

Here's the function :

```js
 import { logger } from '../config/logger';

 export async function assertPageLoaded(
  { path, pageIndicatorLocator },
  templateParams = {}
) {
  if (!path || !pageIndicatorLocator) {
    logger.error(
      'Every page must have path and pageIndicatorLocator constants'
    );
  }
  const finalPath = formatTemplate(path, templateParams);

  await page.waitForSelector(pageIndicatorLocator, { visible: true });
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (page.url() === finalPath) {
      logger.debug(`Current page is the same as expected: ${page.url()}`);
      resolve();
    } else {
      logger.error(`Current page seems to be at the wrong location.
        Expected: ${finalPath}
        But was:  ${page.url()}`);
      reject();
    }
  });
}
```

and here's a test that fails:

```
test('Logs an error if {pageIndicatorLocator} is not passed', async () => {
   await expect(() => navigationUtils.assertPageLoaded({ path: path })).rejects.toThrowError('Every page must have path and pageIndicatorLocator constants');
   });
```

I also tried to use `jest.spyOn()` to spy on logger :

```
test('Logs an error if {pageIndicatorLocator} is not passed', async () => {
jest.spyOn(logger, 'error');
await navigationUtils.assertPageLoaded({ path: path });
const callArg = logger.error.mock.calls[0][0];
expect(callArg).toEqual('Every page must have path and pageIndicatorLocator constants');
})
```

But it failed as well. Has anyone solved an issue like this before?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: does your logger.error method throw an error or just log an error somewhere? You are expecting an error to be thrown in your test. Is this correct?

Comment: The logger just logs as error somewhere (at the level 'info'). I'm expecting this log in my test, correct